# An example of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ whose set of accumulation point is $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find an example of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ whose set of accumulation point is $\mathbb{N}$, or whose set of accumulation point is $\mathbb{R}$. 
I would like to show my progress but I'm stuck.

Comment: For the second one you can take $\;\Bbb Q\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

For $\mathbb{R}$: take a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$. Take the sequence whose $n$th term is $f(n)$. This works because we obtain every rational number, and every real number has a sequence of distinct rational numbers converging to it.

For $\mathbb{N}$: Take a bijection $g: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N^2}$. Take the sequence whose $n$th term is the first coordinate of $g(n)$. This works because we obtain every natural number infinitely many times.

Comment: An explicit example: 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …